# P4: how to make perforce (p4) work with symlinks?

Tags: perforce

I have a perforce workspace setup under /temp/myperforceworkspace and I have created a link in my home folder to point to /temp/myperforceworkspace but whenever I run p4 commands it can't recognise that I am in a valid workspace folder.

how can I convince p4 that I really am in the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your alternate folder name as an AltRoot in your client spec.

And there are other approaches.

See this writeup for more details: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Symbolic-Links-and-Workspace-Roots